# c# Xamarin AutoCompleteTextView shows nothing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, autocompletetextview

In Xamarin Android, I'm trying to bind an object to AutocompleteTextView to show name/surname, but nothing is displayed into the AutocompleteTextView.. (with a ListView instead of AutocompleteTextView everything works)
Into AutocompleteTextView i would like to show the name a Player from a List.

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private AutoCompleteTextView autocomplete;
    private CustomAdapter adapter;
    public List<Player> players;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        players = new List<Player>();
        players.Add(new Player("James"));
        players.Add(new Player("John"));
        players.Add(new Player("Jack"));
        players.Add(new Player("Hugo"));

        autocomplete = FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.autocomplete);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.model, players);

        autocomplete.Adapter = adapter;
    }

    ..
```

**CustomAdapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter : ArrayAdapter
{
    private Context c;
    private List<Player> players;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Player> objects) : base(context, resource, objects)
    {
        this.c = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.players = objects;
    }

    public override Android.Views.View GetView(int position, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (inflater == null)
        {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)c.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        }

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.Inflate(resource, parent, false);
        }

        MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(convertView);
        holder.NameTxt.Text = players[position].Name;

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**Player**

```
public class Player
{
    public String name;

    public Player(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
    }
}
```

**CustomItem**

```
public class CustomItem
{
    public string Heading { get; set; }
}
```

**MyHolder**

```
public class MyHolder
{
    public TextView NameTxt;

    public MyHolder(Android.Views.View itemView)
    {
        NameTxt = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nameTxt);
    }
}
```

Here **model.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation = "horizontal"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent">
    <TextView 
    android:text = "Medium Text"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:id = "@+id/nameTxt"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here **activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/autocomplete" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to pass in an array of type `string` with `ArrayAdapter` directly.

```
players = new List<Player>();
players.Add(new Player("James"));
players.Add(new Player("John"));
players.Add(new Player("Jack"));
players.Add(new Player("Hugo"));
List<string> nameList = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in players)
  {
     nameList.Add(item.Name);
  }
autocomplete = FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.autocomplete);
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.model, Resource.Id.nameTxt, nameList);
autocomplete.Adapter = arrayAdapter;
```

if you want pass `List<Player>`,you should let your custom Adapter implement the `Filterable` interface